# Заливка скошеных углов

Tags: javascript, html, css

Есть 2 дива стоящих друг за другом, нужно сделать скошеную черту между ними **посредине** , и сделать так что бы при наведении заливалось другим дивом до все скошеную часть , а не за ее пределы. Как это можно сделать ?
Думаю можно сделать с js svg , но есть ли варики без них ?

```css
.parent {
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 600px;
}
.hid {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  width:100%;
  height: 200px;
background: green;
}
.child {
  float: left;
  width: 50%;
  height: 200px;
  background: violet;
  position: relative;
}
.child2 {
  background: #000;
  float: left;
  width: 50%;
  height: 200px;
  position: relative;
}
.child:hover > .hid,
.child2:hover > .hid{
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
    <div class="child">
      <div class="hid"></div>
      
    </div>
    <div class="child2">
      <div class="hid"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: может помочь: [transform: skew](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform-function/skew)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вариант с `clip-path`

```css
*{
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.parent{
    height: 100vh;
    width: 100vw;    
    position: relative;
}
[class^=child-]{
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute; top: 0;
}
.child-1{
    left: 0;
    background: green;
    -webkit-clip-path: polygon(0 0, 0 100%, 100% 100%);
    clip-path: polygon(0 0, 0 100%, 100% 100%);
}
.child-2{    
    right: 0;
    background: blue;
    -webkit-clip-path: polygon(0 0, 100% 0, 100% 100%);
    clip-path: polygon(0 0, 100% 0, 100% 100%);
}

[class^=child-]:hover{
    opacity: .5;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
    <div class="child-1"></div>      
    <div class="child-2"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

> но есть ли варики без них ?

Да возможны.

```css
.block1{
 display:table-cell; 
 border-bottom: 100px solid red;
 border-left: 50px solid red;
 border-right: 50px solid transparent;
 height: 0;
 width: 100px; 
}
.block2{
 display:table-cell;
 position:relative;
 border-bottom: 100px solid blue;
 border-right: 50px solid transparent;
 border-left: 50px solid blue;
 height: 0;
 width: 100px;
 left:-50px;
 transform:rotate(180deg); 
 z-index:2;
}
```

```html
<div class="block1"></div>
<div class="block2"></div>
```

Comment: Но так использовать, наверное только для фона с z-index: - слой;